# promises and for loops

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have this code:

```
function ProductObj(product, i) {
    var self = this;

    self.photo = product.photos.medium_half;
    self.title = product.name;
    self.tagline = product.tagline;
    self.url = product.url;

    self.htmlView = "";
    self.index = i;


    //this async call is slow, very slow
    self.updateHTML = function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            $.get('product-template.html', function (template) {
                self.htmlView = template.replace('{image}', self.photo)
                    .replace('{title}', self.title)
                    .replace('{tagline}', self.tagline)
                    .replace('{url}', self.url);

                console.log('updateHTML ' + self.index + ' ran');
                resolve();
            });
        });
    };
}
```

when self.updateHTML is called, self.updateDOM is called at the same time

```
 self.updateDOM = function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            var thisHTML = '';

            for( var i = 0; i < self.products.length; i++) {

                if (i % 3 === 0 ) {
                    thisHTML += "<div class='row'>";
                    console.log('START')
                }

                thisHTML += self.products[i].htmlView;

                if ((i % 3 === 2) || i === (self.products.length - 1) ) {
                    thisHTML += "</div>";
                    console.log('finish')
                }

                if(i === (self.products.length -1)) {
                    $("#content").append(thisHTML);
                }
            }
            resolve();
        })
    }
```

naturally, I used promises to attempt to fix this as such

```
 page.getProducts('data.json')
        .then( page.updateProductHTML )
        .then( page.updateDOM )
        .then( someOtherFunction );
```

`Page.getProducts` executes first and returns a promise to `page.updateProductHTML`. So far my promise in `page.updateProductHTML` is resolving before assignments can finish in `self.updateHTML` and `updateDOM` is firing but it needs values from updateHTML before it can finish

The problem arises from this `page.updateProductHTML` as it runs this code

```
self.updateProductHTML = function() {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            for( var i = 0; i < self.products.length; i++){

                self.products[i].updateHTML();

            }
            resolve();
        })
    };
```

I attempted to wrap the above code in a promise and resolve outside of the for loop but the `$.get()` call is still working

from what I understand I need to keep updateHTML in a promise but it doesn't seem to do anything different in its present state since I can't use a `.then` in my for loop in `page.updateProductHTML`

How do I force `page.updateProductHTML` to not resolve until it finishes its calls in `self.updateHTML`?

small recap I want this order `self.getProducts() => self.updateProducts => sef.updateDOM => other functions`

Comment: would you mind posting a simple working solution of your problem? It looks like a minor wiring problem you have. It would be better to understand the problem if you have a sample.

Comment: Is `product-template.html` the same for each product? Then you can fetch it only once before doing everything in a loop, and updateHTML does not need to be async.

Comment: @artem you're right, doing that speeds it up to be faster than my updateDOM method but the promise is still broken

Comment: Can you fetch it in the first promise before anything else and pass the HTML string as parameter when calling updateHTML() for every product, then call updateDOM, all within the first promise callback, without involving any other promises? Or is there something else supposed to be in updateHTML() that requires it to be async?

Comment: If you're in an environment that allows you to use arrow functions like this, there is zero reason to use the `var self = this;` pattern FYI. Just use `this` and you're good.

Comment: Working on legacy code. Start changing too much and problems will arise. Not worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use `Promise.all()`:

```
self.updateProductHTML = function() {
  return Promise.all(self.products.map(product => product.updateHTML()));
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use promise.all, which waits till all of your promises are resolved and then executes the other methods which are dependent on the earlier methods.

An example is here on my [Codepen](http://codepen.io/jsreekanth/pen/gLOaem?editors=0002) link

```js
self.updateProductHTML = function() {
  var updateMethods = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < self.products.length; i++) {
    updateMethods.push(self.products[i].updateHTML());
  }
  return Promise.all(updateMethods);
}

self.updateDOM = function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < self.products.length; i++) {

    if (i % 3 === 0) {
      thisHTML += "<div class='row'>";
      console.log('START')
    }

    thisHTML += self.products[i].htmlView;

    if ((i % 3 === 2) || i === (self.products.length - 1)) {
      thisHTML += "</div>";
      console.log('finish')
    }

    if (i === (self.products.length - 1)) {
      $("#content").append(thisHTML);
    }
  }
}

updateProductHTML().then(updateDOM);
```